# Clipping raster-image increases file size

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, file-size

Working with QGIS 2.4.0 Chugiak I have a question regarding the clipping of raster images. I have an aerial picture that I want to clip using the extents of a shapefile. So far so good, I used the raster/extraction/clipper tool to do this. The problem is that the file size of my output raster is nearly three times larger than the original file (i.e. 725.283 and 249.693 kb respectively), whereas it covers a smaller surface.

Why is my file larger? And is there any way to 'set' the output file size?

The help function of clipper refers to the following page: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html Though I cannot make much out of it.

I am relatively new to QGIS.

Comment: Usually it means that the original is compressed but the clipped tiff is uncompressed. You must read about the GDAL GeoTIFF driver and compression options.

Comment: If you want to use compression on your output dataset you have to edit the command, as shown at the bottom of the clipper interface, and incorporate the creation options with the `-co` flag. For a GeoTiff you could for example include `-co compress=lzw` to employ lossless LZW compression. We would need to know more about your dataset though to be able to help you (for instance via [`gdlainfo`](http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html)).

Comment: Uncompressed TIFF images are usually faster.

Comment: Thanks to all for the replies. This may indeed be a compression problem, I had not thought of that. Yes Kersten I did notice the console in the clipper interface, though I have not figured out how to use this.
I am trying to run gdalinfo from the Python console in QGIS but I have no experience with this. Does anyone know of a proper tutorial to familiarize myself? Cheers

Comment: You can go to `Raster > Miscellaneous > Information` to have `gdalinfo` run on your raster file. You can't run it directly form the Python console because it isn't a Python script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run the raster clip tool in QGIS, it shows you the exact GDAL command that will be run in the bottom section of the dialog box.

[image: Raster clip tool]

By clicking the pen button to the right of the command, you can edit it directly and add in a compression configuration option. In my example, this is the starting command:

`gdalwarp -q -cutline /tmp/mask.shp -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff /tmp/453A.tif /tmp/output.tif`

You can change this to be:

`gdalwarp -q -cutline /tmp/mask.shp -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff -co "COMPRESS=LZW" /tmp/453A.tif /tmp/output.tif`

The extra `-co "COMPRESS=LZW"` is just one of many possible compression options you can use with GeoTIFF files. The [GDAL documentation](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html) has more information on all the options.

Comment: Many thanks, that was exactly what I needed. The file is still 409.019 kb, so nearly double as big as the original, but rendering is much faster. That website I had seen but I could not understand much of it. Gdalinfo showed that the compression was indeed 'ticked off' for the first clip, so this was indeed the problem.

Comment: When you run `gdalinfo`, what does it report for compression? We should be able to replicate it in the second file once we know. My guess is that it might be lossy-JPEG if it is considerably smaller than LZW.

Comment: This is what it says for the original image: 'Pixel Size = (0.000738433000001,-0.000738432999949)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL' and this is what it says for the clipped image: 'Pixel Size = (0.000738423955088,-0.000738437979722)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL'

Comment: Is it possible you accidentally got the metadata for the same image twice since both are the same?

Comment: They are not, look at the pixel size ;)

Comment: I missed the small diff!

Comment: The only difference I can find is in the colourbands: 'Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha' For the original, and: 'Band 1 Block=8972x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  NoData Value=255
Band 2 Block=8972x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  NoData Value=255
Band 3 Block=8972x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  NoData Value=255
...' for the clipped 1

Answer (score 3):

Update for QGIS versions 3 and up: the compression option is now integrated in the `Raster` -> `Extraction` -> `Clip raster by mask layer` plugin, and in most other plugins which produce raster files.

Under `Advanced parameters` -> `Profile`, selecting either `Low compression` or `High compression` will yield a smaller file.

These compression options are lossless, but you can choose also lossy options:

- `Low compression`  -> `-co PACKBITS` (lossless)
- `High compression` -> `-co DEFLATE` (lossless)
- `JPEG compression` -> `-co JPEG_QUALITY=75` (lossy: beware!)

[image: Clip raster by mask layer]