# QGIS clipper taking forever

Tags: qgis, clip, performance

As the project requires, I built virtual raster catalog merging two raster DEM files. Because I don't want to use the whole surface of the new Virtual Raster, I went on to clip a desired rectangle. When I do this, QGIS is taking forever to complete the process (forever meaning it never completes it) and after a while, I have to close the whole program and restart it. I found this problem to be more often in the latest versions of QGIS (I'm using the latest, 2.14.2 version).
ps. I checked the newly created file while it was still processed and the file size was ridiculously large (I mean gigabytes, while in the past the output was with smaller file sizes).

Comment: A repeatable test case with data and description of the work flow would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share details about your clip settings? Might be related to http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/164385/187

Comment: Hmmm... I deleted QGIS version 2.14 and installed QGIS 2.2.0 and the problem is magically solved. Like I said, I don't have luck with new QGIS versions when it comes to clipping so I guess I will just stick to the older ones:)